# Duplicate results in Q query involving many to one relation to a model

Tags: django, django-1.5, django-q

I have a `Car` model and a `Passenger` model with a ForeignKey to a `Car` object.  Both `Car` and `Passenger` models have a `name` field.

I want to get all the cars that contain 'banana' in either the car or any passenger name, so I tried:

```
from django.db.models import Q
...
name = 'banana'
cars = Car.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=name) | Q(passenger__name__icontains=name))
```

Curiously, when I have a `Car` named 'banana' and three passengers in it called anything (matching or not 'banana'), it returns three times the matching `Car`.

The questions are:

- Why?
- How to return only once the car? I think that `.distinct()` would work, but maybe there is a better way.

I am using Django 1.5.

Comment: use distinct() after filter method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have answered **how** to get what you want, but you also asked **why**, so here goes:

Your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cars c
LEFT JOIN passengers p ON p.car_id = c.id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%banana%' OR p.name LIKE '%banana%'
```

Basically, you're joining cars to passengers, and there are three passengers in a car where the car.name is 'banana'. So that returns three rows.